Why cppcheck finds different issues when header and source files are separate and when they are manually merged?
I prepared 2 simples files, test.hpp:
struct Inner
{
    int y;
    int z{5};
};

struct Struct
{
    int x{4};
    Inner inner;
};

class Class
{
    Class(int i) {}
};

And test.cpp:
#include "test.hpp"

int main()
{
    Struct s;
    return s.x;
}

I would expect to get notified about all unusedStructMembers and about a lack of explicit keyword. I added this constructor just to see if header file will be included into a source file. Now, running
cppcheck --std=c++17 --enable=style --platform=unix64 test.hpp

with Cppcheck 2.14 dev gives such output:
test.hpp
Checking test.hpp ...
test.hpp:15:5: style: Class 'Class' has a constructor with 1 argument that is not explicit. [noExplicitConstructor]
    Class(int i) {}
    ^
test.hpp:3:9: style: struct member 'Inner::y' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    int y;
        ^
test.hpp:4:9: style: struct member 'Inner::z' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    int z{5};
        ^
test.hpp:9:9: style: struct member 'Struct::x' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    int x{4};
        ^
test.hpp:10:11: style: struct member 'Struct::inner' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    Inner inner;
          ^

The results are just like I expected, cppcheck detected all issues, but couldn't know Struct::x was used in source file, so we got a false positive.
Running cppcheck on test.cpp gives only:
Checking test.cpp ...
test.hpp:15:5: style: Class 'Class' has a constructor with 1 argument that is not explicit. [noExplicitConstructor]
    Class(int i) {}
    ^

I do not understand why unusedMembers were not detected while explicit constructor was... Variables besides Struct::x are still not being used. Now, the most interesting parts is when I merge the two files, either manually or with a command:
g++ test.cpp -E -P > testEP.cpp

Then the cppcheck output is just as I would expect from the very beginning:
$ cppcheck --std=c++17 --enable=style --platform=unix64 testEP.cpp
Checking testEP.cpp ...
testEP.cpp:13:5: style: Class 'Class' has a constructor with 1 argument that is not explicit. [noExplicitConstructor]
    Class(int i) {}
    ^
testEP.cpp:3:9: style: struct member 'Inner::y' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    int y;
        ^
testEP.cpp:4:9: style: struct member 'Inner::z' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    int z{5};
        ^
testEP.cpp:9:11: style: struct member 'Struct::inner' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    Inner inner;
          ^

Now cppcheck correctly detected all issues and generated no false positives.
What's going on and how I can get the best output without manually merging the files? Running the g++ -E -P on the project including standard library (or boost...) causes its size and processing time to explode.

I suppose cppcheck checks file as source not as header.

i.e compiling test.hpp (or concatenation of both file), the TU is complete. Classes defined in that TU cannot be used outside of that TU (unless copy/pasted), so unused member might be flagged (I would expect warning for unused class Class)

On the other side, when compiling test.cpp, "test.hpp" is known to be a header, which might be shared with other cpp, so members (and classes) might be used elsewhere. checking the project though, might retrieve the warning you got (it requires trans-TU analysis, not sure cppcheck handle that and at which point).
